# One UIView animation cancels the other one in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

In my iOS app I'm trying to perform 2 animations at the same time. However, the code below doesn't do what I want. It cancels the first animation and only the second one (the one from notification) is performed. As for the first on it just gets to the end result after 1 second.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    CGRect tempRect = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, toolbar.frame.size.width, toolbar.frame.size.height);
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0f
    animations: ^ {
        toolbar.frame = tempRect;
    }
    completion: ^ (BOOL finished) {
        [toolbar setHidden: YES];
        isPlayerToolbarActive = NO;
    }];
});

[
    [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"animateSidePanels"
    object: @"removingPlayerToolbar"];

// notification is sent here

-
(void) animateSidePanels: (NSNotification * ) notification {
    if ([notification.object isEqualToString: @"removingPlayerToolbar"]) {
        [self.interactionsViewController performExtendAnimation: self.interactionsViewController.view.frame.size.height + 44
        withDuration: 1.0f
        completion: ^ (BOOL finished) {

        }];
    }
}

-(void)performExtendAnimation:(CGFloat)newHeight withDuration:(CGFloat)duration completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                 self.view.frame.origin.y,
                                 self.view.frame.size.width,
                                 newHeight);
    self.view.frame = newFrame;

}completion: completion];
```

}
Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Comment: In what relation are the `toolbar` and `self.interactionsViewController.view`? My guess is, that the toolbar is a subview of the interaction controller's view. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `UIView`'s `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` method and provide `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` and `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent` in options.

Comment: This may also help, but we don't see inside the `performExtendAnimation:...` so we don't know what is animated.

Answer (score 1):

To animate the `interactionViewController`'s extend animation, use method:

```
+[UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:]
```

with option `UIViewAnimationOption`**`AllowAnimatedContent`**.